# JPA query to return a list of entities but replacing one field with the value from another entity

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Suppose I have two tables as following:

**contact**

- id
- name
- email
- city_id
- created_at
- updated_at

**note**

- id
- title
- description
- contact_id
- created_at
- updated_at

I would like to get a list of **contacts** by city order by updated_at. But the **contact.updated_at** should have the value of the **latest note.updated_at** related to that contact.

Using a native query I was able to achieve this with:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.email, c.city_id, c.created_at,
       (SELECT MAX(n.updated_at) FROM note n WHERE n.contact_id = c.id) AS updated_at
   FROM contact c
   WHERE c.city_id = cityIdValue
```

But as a project requirement I can't use native queries.

It would be possible to obtain this result using a Spring Data repository method or a JPA Query?

Thanks!!

Comment: You can't return the result as a list of entities. Just create a DTO and use the `NEW` operator with your query

Comment: could you do 2 queries and merge their results java side? one for selecting contacts and another one for selecting a List<Pair<note.ContactId,max(note.updated_at)>